# NSMutableArray search string

Tags: objective-c

I've a person object which has `NSString` properties `firstname`, `lastname`, `birthday`, and `NSMutableDictionary` of different phone numbers of that person.

I've added different person objects in an `NSMutableArray` named `personArray`.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObjectPassingTest%3a) method on `NSArray`. Something like this:

```
return [personArray[[personArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^ (id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL stop) {
    return [lastName isEqualToString:[obj lastName]];
}]] phoneNumber];
```

You get the idea.

Comment: @user2769614: Try putting that code in your phoneNUmberForLastName method. It should work.

Comment: that throws error 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Person phoneNumber]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: phone numbers are in NSMutableDictionary inside person object

Comment: @user2769614: I can't help you with that unless I can see the Person class.

Comment: these are the variables in person object                            {
    NSString *firstName;
    NSString *lastName;
    NSString *birthday;
    NSMutableDictionary *phoneNumbers;
}

Comment: @user2769614: You want to return phoneNumbers instead of phoneNumber, it sounds like.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
-(NSArray *) phoneNumberFor:(NSString *)lastName{
NSInteger indx = [self.personArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(Person *aPerson, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [aPerson.lastname isEqualToString:lastName];
}];
if (indx != NSNotFound) {
    return [self.personArray[indx] phoneNumbers].allValues;
}else{
    return nil;
}
```

}

In this example, I'm assuming an array property called personArray, a class name of "Person" for your person objects, and a mutable dictionary called phoneNumbers. I'm also assuming that the dictionary contains several keys and values, where all of the values are phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can get object from array of the given lastname like as follow:-

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastname == '%@'", lastname];
NSArray *foundPersonArray = [personArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog("found person object = %@",foundPersonArray);
```

But if you want to search multiple object of same lastname from array then you can do following:-

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastname LIKE[c] %@", lastname];
NSArray *foundPersonArray = [personArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog("found person object = %@",foundPersonArray);
```