# Search NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, search, nsarray

I need to write a method that searches for a phone number inside `personArray` and should return the name associated with that phone number.

```
- (NSString *) nameForNumber:(NSString *)phoneNumber{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do, is to learn how to use the NSArray method indexOfObjectPassingTest:. This is a very useful method for finding things in arrays. You current question can be solved like this:

```
- (NSString *) nameForNumber:(NSString *)phoneNumber{
    NSInteger indx = [self.personArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(Person *aPerson, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [aPerson.phoneNumbers.allValues containsObject:phoneNumber];
    }];
    if (indx != NSNotFound) {
        return [self.personArray[indx] lastname];
    }else{
        return @"Not Found";
    }
}
```

The names I'm using are based on the same assumptions that I made in my answer to one of your other questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795556/nsmutablearray-search-string)).